# In JavaFX how to keep in the center of window a moving character drawn on a canvas?

Tags: javafx, canvas

I'm very new to JavaFX and currently working on a rouge like game in 2D, which uses GUI made with JavaFX. The moving character is drawn on the canvas with GraphicContext2D. There is only one canvas, and I'd like to solve my problem without overlaying if possible. Canvas is added to Borderpane as center, Scene created with this Borderpane, for the Stage this Scene was set. Canvas is redrawn after moving with character on KeyEvent. I've already made the Stage resizable. Everything is running well, with the exception that I just cannot keep my moving character on the center in the window and when canvas is bigger than the window it can move out of this window.
How can I keep my dear moving character in the middle?

OK, here is a very, very simplified version, but with same problem, character does not stay in middle, it can run off from window then return as canvas is set greater than window.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    String[][] map = new String[40][20];
    int[] playerCoords = {3,10};

    //colored.png downloaded from https://kenney.nl/assets/bit-pack
    Image tileset = new Image("/colored.png", 815 * 2, 373 * 2, true, false);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(
            20 * 32,
            40 * 32);
    GraphicsContext context = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(canvas);
        map[3][10] = "p";

        refresh();
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
            case UP:
                this.movePlayer(true);
                refresh();
                break;
            case DOWN:
                this.movePlayer(false);
                refresh();
                break;}});
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    void movePlayer(boolean up){
        int direction = up ? -1 : 1;
        int newPosRow = playerCoords[0] + direction;
        if ( newPosRow >= 0 && newPosRow < map.length) {
            map[playerCoords[0]][playerCoords[1]] = null;
            playerCoords[0] = newPosRow;
            map[playerCoords[0]][playerCoords[1]] = "p";
        }
    }

    void refresh(){
        context.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++ ){
            for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++){
                if (map[i][j] != null && map[i][j].equals("p")){
                    //player Tile 28, 0
                    context.drawImage(tileset, 952,0, 32,32,j * 32,i * 32, 32,32);
                } else{
                    context.drawImage(tileset, 0,0, 32,32,j * 32,i * 32, 32,32);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That context.drawImage method is a bit tricky, it happened also to me, when those many input parameter numbers were incorrect. Also I use a separate class App to run the application but it is really short it just calls Main.main(args).

Comment: It can be downloaded from https://kenney.nl/assets/bit-pack

Comment: I noticed that I'm not using exactly the same png, but I've checked it with this current one I've downloaded e few moments ago, it works with it, just not nice, because for that those numbers in context.drawImage should be readjusted.

Comment: Ok, not in the contect.drawImage, but at the top, where I read the png for creating the Image object, tileset. File size is 815 x 373.

Comment: Corrected the file size in the example code here.

Comment: Try studying this info on a [canvas-based tile engine for JavaFX](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/writing-a-tile-engine-in-javafx.html).  Unfortunately, the original blog post is gone (perhaps you could find it in the way back machine).  However the info from the link I provided might still be helpful.  There is [source code for the tile engine in git](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/writing-a-tile-engine-in-javafx.html) if you want to investigate how it accomplishes this task.  It is an exceptionally clever piece of work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems there is not an easy JavaFX solution currently. But if someone knows one, thanks for sharing. :-)
In the meantime I thought about an algorythmic solution by transforming coords according to absolute and relative (player placed in middle) coordinates of the player. It's very far from perfect, it changes only the rowCoords of map, as the player can move only vertically in this example, and it works with a canvas not much greater than the window size. I needed to change only the refresh method. There is something I do not understand at the moment,
it works with substracting centerCol from player's row coord

```
int centerRow = map.length/2;
int centerCol = map[0].length/2;
int mapRowDiff = playerCoords[0] - centerCol;
```

not with substracting centerRow from player's row coord

```
int centerRow = map.length/2;
int centerCol = map[0].length/2;
int mapRowDiff = playerCoords[0] -  centerRow;
```

But at least it started working.
And here is my refresh() with the transformation, it became a bit complex.

```
    void refresh(){
        context.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        int centerRow = map.length/2;
        int centerCol = map[0].length/2;
        int mapRowDiff = playerCoords[0] - centerCol;
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++ ){
            for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++){
                if (mapRowDiff >= 0
                        && mapRowDiff < map.length) {
                    if (map[mapRowDiff][j] != null && map[mapRowDiff][j].equals("p")) {
                        //player Tile 28, 0
                        context.drawImage(tileset, 952, 0, 32, 32, j * 32, i * 32, 32, 32);
                    } else {
                        context.drawImage(tileset, 0, 0, 32, 32, j * 32, i * 32, 32, 32);
                    }
                } else {
                    context.drawImage(tileset, 0, 34, 32, 32, j * 32, i * 32, 32, 32);
                }
            }
            mapRowDiff++;
        }
    }
```